# Is there a version of Ocarina of Time where the village tree doesn't change?

Tags: version-differences, zelda-ocarina-of-time

In Zelda: Ocarina of Time, the lone tree in Kakariko Village and one of the trees next to the entrance to Castle Town change between the two eras. While they look like any other tree when Link is a kid, if you visit these areas with adult Link you'll see the trees are thickening near the top and their branches point upwards.

I've played through different versions of the game (N64, GameCube, 3DS) and the above is true for all of them. However, I could have sworn I remember playing through the game at least once and not seeing any difference in the Kakariko Village tree between the two eras.

I had to re-buy the N64 version when I lost the original cartridge, so I'm wondering if my first one was a version of the game where the tree was the same in both eras. Was there ever such a version?

Here are some pictures that demonstrate what I'm asking about.

The tree in the village as it originally is, from the introductory cut-scene on Link's first visit (not the best view but I couldn't find another). It should be obvious that it looks like any other tree in the game.

[image: The tree in the village as it originally is]

The tree in the village once Link is an adult, in any version of OoT I can find nowadays. It obviously looks very different:

[image: The tree in the village once Link is an adult]

There is also this screenshot, which shows the tree while the village is on fire (which only happens when Link is an adult) but having its original shape. This is the way I remember it when I first played the game:

[image: the tree while the village is on fire]

Comment: Hello. If you think this question is an unsuitable one, I believe it's common courtesy to explain why.

Comment: From memory, there were at least 3 different versions of Ocarina of Time, but other than the Fire Temple music and blood color, I couldn't tell what changes they made.

Comment: @Powerlord they also changed some of the symbols in the spirit temple I believe. TheGameTheorists did a video that mentioned these changes if you wanted to see here: https://youtube.com/watch?v=59LHQ1bKS-M

Comment: @GeorgeT what exactly do you mean, I don't remember the tree changing significantly, I have the original N64 version, and if you include a before growing up and after picture I'll check for you.

Comment: @Parzival: I added a few screenshots.

Comment: @GeorgeT weird, I don't remember the village being on fire ever, and i did finish playing through the entire version of OOT. But I'll check for you and get back to you in a few days when I can, I'm pretty busy with school.

Comment: This is essentially asking us to identify a game from memory.  None of the screenshots are from the game you're looking for, they're just there to demonstrate your point.

Comment: Not really. It's asking about version differences, which we even have a tag for (yes, I know that doesn't automatically make something on-topic). It doesn't have any of the problems that make ITGs bad questions. There's no guessing game involved here.

Comment: Probably a region/localisation issue. What region did you originally buy the game from? Which version is the copy you are playing now? (US, EU, JP etc etc)

Comment: @Robotnik: All versions I've played are EU. This is part of the reason I find it surprising I've never seen the difference mentioned anywhere, as the first EU version was the 3rd or 4th US one. The only alternative is that I somehow finished the game at least once without ever noticing the tree looked different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to see the tree change, even when I played through the entire game again. I do own the original game, so I conclude it never does change. Yes, i went back after each dungeon, and if i could i did it as a kid and an adult. The tree never changed.

Comment: You didn't see the tree change, so you conclude that it does change? I think you accidentally some words there.

Comment: You're not supposed to see it change in front of your eyes; the question is whether it's different when you're an adult than when you're a kid.

Comment: yes, i went back after each dungeon, and if i could i did it as a kid and an adult.

Comment: @Parzival: Just to be clear: Are you saying that even when you're an adult, the tree looks the same as all the other trees in the game? It looks like in the 1st and 3rd screenshots I posted, but NOT like it is in the second one?

Comment: yes, that is what im saying.

Comment: Thanks! So they made it different in subsequent versions for some reason. I wonder why they did that.

Comment: who knows, maybe they wanted to add more changes that would make it feel more like 7 years, like a new tree.